# Weblogic 12.2.1, links error

Tags: java, spring, weblogic

i have an spring mvc application running well with tomcat.

But when i try run with weblogic dont redirect.

For Example:
My jsp has a link: `<a href="new">New User</a>`

My controller catch the url:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/new" }, method = { org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.GET })
    public ModelAndView newUser() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("UserForm");
        model.addObject("user", new User());
        return model;
    }
```

This run on tomcat but when i try with weblogic he redirect to "http://localhost:7001/new" and must be "http://localhost:7001/HibernateJavaBased/new"

How can i set up the weblogic server?

UPDATE 1: my App is java config this is the initializer

```
public class SpringWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(ApplicationContextConfig.class);
        ctx.setServletContext(container);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/");
        System.out.println(ctx.getServletContext().getContextPath());

        servlet.setInitParameter("contextClass", ctx.getClass().getName());
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx));
    }
}
```

And the AppConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({ "net.codejava.spring" })
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ApplicationContextConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean(name = { "viewResolver" })
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe on tomcat you have configured the context root. You can configure the context root in web logic as well with the file weblogic.xml If you do not have already a file weblogic.xml, make a new file weblogic.xml under /WEB-INF/ directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<wls:weblogic-web-app
xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd
http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app
http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">

     <wls:weblogic-version>12.2.1</wls:weblogic-version>
     <wls:context-root>HibernateJavaBased</wls:context-root>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thx for reply but dont work. I get the App run if i set the context-root like "HibernateJavaBased/" but i cant understand the reason why weblogic need this change.

Comment: Can you post your web.xml as well?

Comment: update the main post.
running with tomcat and weblogic , tomcat add an slash and weblogic dont...

Comment: Where did you configure the string HibernateJavaBased?Can you do a search in your web application for the string HibernateJavaBased and tell me where is it used.

Comment: I guess what you are doing is right click on your project ->Properties->Web Project Properties and then you set the context root. Is this what you do?When you set the context root like this I think it is just changes a file that the     tomcat server uses internally with eclipse. So if the context path that you are setting it is only used in the internal tomcat server. Do you deploy the application as a war or as an ear?

Comment: When you put the weblogic.xml file in the web-inf directory and you have deployed the application in Web logic can you access the page http://localhost:7001/HibernateJavaBased ?

Comment: yes the context root is in Project properties.
If i put weblogic.xml i can Access to that url; weblogic.XML use the same context root that Project properties.

Comment: So, when you are in page localhost:7001/HibernateJavaBased and you press the button New User what happens?

Comment: with weblogic redirect to localhost:7001/new and must be localhost:7001/HibernateJavaBased/new

Comment: So in web logic you are in page localhost:7001/HibernateJavaBased and then you press New and you go to localhost:7001/new?

Comment: yes. in tomcat go to localhost:7001/HibernateJavaBased/new but weblogic dont. The unique solution i find is set context root to "HibernateJavaBased/" or use some tag like c:url in all my links.

Comment: Do you deploy the application as a war or as an ear?